# Restricting URL Access based on the Device's ID (Phone number)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

Is there a possibility to design a **web API (ASP.NET) URL** which can be accessed only from a **specific mobile device (preferably based on Phone number)**, This is more like a verification of a mobile device when it tries to open a specific encoded URL, Kindly suggest me any possibilities that would help for the above requirement or any other workarounds for achieving the same?

Comment: What makes you think all web requests done through mobile browsers include the phone number of the phone?

Comment: This is a specific requirement , where we are asked to verify if the URL is being opened by the intended recipient and only in the expected Phone number, That is cause for this.

Comment: Also Do you mean it isn't always accessible using a method or anything like a restriction from the service provider level?

Comment: When you browse to a website using your phone, in the vast majority of cases, you don't include your phone number in the request. You simply won't have access to it when your clients connect, so you won't be able to use it.

Comment: Your requirement might be satisfied only if you access the webAPI from a custom mobile app (not a browser) that can pick up the phone number and send it to your server endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Add a attribute  on your each controller method. In CanAccess property do your logic whether this will have a access.

```
[RequiredPermissions(UserPermission.CanAccess)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , Can you please give us little more insight on this controller property?